# Does this ThreadPoolExecutor need synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, compilation, event-loop

An executor of the given configuration:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                1, // corePoolSize
                1, // maximumPoolSize
                0, // keepAliveTime
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, // TimeUnit
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<>() // Task queue
        );
```

Would keep the single Thread alive, while any extra tasks executed would be added to the FIFO LinkedBlockingQueue.

According to what the source code reads, everything happening in this worker Thread is always sequential.

The Runnable stack-frames that are created and inserted onto the queue would still be affected by normal memory ordering effects, so fences are still required for loads and stores, BUT...

In practice, if everything is sequential it seems clear to me, that no race conditions will ever occur, so the only issue seems to be Thread caching, also known as memory hoisting, and load simplification (for double-checking)

BUT... If Runnable stack-frames... appearing as part of their "unique scope"...

```
Runnable toExecuteA = () -> {
   // code...
};
Runnable toExecuteB = () -> {
   // code...
};
```

Seems to me that their reorderings would ONLY occur within the bounds of their "{}" ...frames.

Since the compile time is not aware which will be the sequence of all Runnables at the moment of execution A, and B will never get interleaved, and since the same Thread is used, the processor will ALSO not interleave the sequence.

So...

- a) no need to synchronize => everything will be sequential.
- b) reorderings are limited within the bounds of the Runnable frames.
- c) loads may be hoisted and simplified, so memory_order_relaxed like
  fences are needed to keep Runnable stack-frame PO.
- d) since sequentiality is enforced across all Runnables, no "acquire"
  and "release" like fences are needed.

Now... EVEN IF the processor devirtualizes ALL CALLS, and manages to order the sequences toExecuteA + toExecuteB + toExecuteC, etc... sequences... into a single uninterrupted sequence... the simplifications and ommitions that the processor may do afterwards will not affect the end result that may have happened still if the event loop would have finished processing.

The ONLY issue then, would be if this processor's core interacts with ANOTHER core from the same processor BEFORE the last line in the sequence of runnables is reached.

Is my observation correct??

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  "A picture is worth a thousand words" and a code example would be worth two thousand.  In general, a single thread doesn't need to synchronize between method invocations.  What you have (in code you've shown) is basically the same thing as Swing's UI thread or the Android UI thread, and that's done to avoid the need for synchronization.  It also isn't "thread safe" (read the docs, that's what is says) and requires ad hoc reasoning by the programmer.  I think you should really expand on the code you want to try, it would help us understand.

Comment: " ONLY issue then, would be if this processor's core interacts with ANOTHER core from the same processor BEFORE the last line in the sequence of runnables is reached." You seem to be describing a context switch here and no, the OS and threading software handles that explicitly.  Processes are switched between cores and CPUs all the time, and no harm done.  It's an old problem and already solved.

Comment: My question was more about what to expect from a single Threaded event loop.
You kind of answered with your "Swing and Android" mention.
What I meant with "interact" is the core running the event loop, making a main memory write, and another core seeing that write... that would be a case in which acquire and release like fences would matter, I think... unless nothing AFTER the write on the writing-core, is of importance to the reading-core side.

Comment: A single thread of execution is always thread safe, absent interference from some other source (thread, hardware, etc.)  You don't have to worry about reads and writes executed by that thread pool.  Calling a method, like `Runnable.run()` doesn't change that, a method call still thread safe.  What you might need to worry about is passing data into the Runnable objects, which does need to be thread safe.  Unless the thread pool synchronizes for you, which it might.  Check the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ONLY issue then, would be if this processor's core interacts with ANOTHER core from the same processor BEFORE the last line in the sequence of runnables is reached.

"Core" is not a Java concept.

> ...Runnable stack-frames...

"Stack frame" is not a Java concept either.

The only thing that matters is that there's more than one thread. The [*Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) is the ultimate authority for questions about interactions between threads.

Your program (what little we can see of it) has two threads; It has the executor's *worker thread,* and it has the thread that created the executor. Let's call that one the "main thread."

The worker will perform a sequence of `run()` function calls for various objects, one after another. Interactions between those different function activations will be no different from how it would be if a single-threaded program executed the same sequence of calls. It really *is* going to be just one thread that does it, and if the operating system chooses to move a thread from one processor to the other, it's the operating system's responsibility to ensure that that happens transparently for your program. It's nothing you need to worry about.

Ditto for interactions that happen entirely within the main thread. It'll be the same as if that thread was the only thread.

The only place where it gets interesting is when there are interactions between tasks that you submit to the Executor and things done by the main thread. (I.E., when the two threads access the same shared variables.) In that case, it's just exactly like any other program with *two* threads because it *is* just a program with two threads. Be sure to use `synchronized` blocks or `ReentrantLock`s when accessing the shared variables, and you'll probably be fine.